# 1286 - Unknown storage engine 'MongoDB' while migrating to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, migration, mongodb-biconnector

I am using MySQL migration tool to migrate my data from MongoDB (via MongoDB BI connector) to MySQL.

All first steps performed well.

At **Create Schemas** step, I get the warning

```
Unknown storage engine 'MongoDB'.
SQL Error: 1286
```

And at **Create Target Results** step, the SQL scripts to create tables fail with the same error output.

Example of query that fails:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trainingDB`.`gradings` (
  `_studentId` VARCHAR(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '{ \"name\": \"studentId\" }',
  `_sessionId` VARCHAR(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '{ \"name\": \"sessionId\" }')
ENGINE = MongoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin
COMMENT = '{ \"collectionName\": \"gradings\" }'
```

Comment: Do you have the corresponding queries ?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with one.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how Mongo works nor the BI Connector. But the `ENGINE = MongoDB` seems odd to me. Does BI Connector provide a custom MySQL engine ? Is this query auto-generated ? If not, maybe you wanted to use `InnoDB` instead ?

Comment: This query is auto-generated

Comment: I am not sure wether or not it provides a custom MySQL engine, however it provides an ODBC Driver which I set up

Comment: I think ODBC drivers are for the application side and may be unrelated to your issue. I just read a little bit about MongoDB BI Connector and it seems to be used to query a MongoDB database with SQL queries, are you sure it can migrate data from MondoDB to MySQL ? If you have any documentation link to share about that, that'd help.

Comment: Ok thanks. I saw [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/migrate-data-from-mongodb-sql-server-milad-firouzi/) and [there](https://www.sqlshack.com/import-data-from-mongodb-to-sql-server-using-ssis/) tutorials to migrate to SQL Server so I intended to do the same to MySQL

Comment: Okay unfortunately I think I can't help about that. Except if you know how to program in PHP and would like to try [Fregata](https://github.com/AymDev/Fregata) (disclaimer: one of my projects) to perform your database migration. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience in PHP. Thanks for your time anyway.